# how can i pass a string containing new line characters to an activity in azure data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am calling a web activity in a pipeline that is sending out an email (via Logic App).

Body of the email is being sent as a parameter from the ADF pipeline.

I am forming this body dynamically and want to embed new line characters in the body when i pass the string to the web activity.

Please suggest how can this be done.

P.S. I've tried embedding "\n" characters already and it is not working

Answer (score 1):

According to [Replacing special characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#replacing-special-characters), the answer is something like this:

> uriComponentToString('%0A')

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

> `</br>`

Answer (score 0):

Open the json code, make sure you are using "\n", instead of "\n"[image]

Comment: do you mean '\n' instead of '\\n' ?     I tried that too but it is not working.