# How to place a new line (line feed) in dynamic expression in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, dynamic-expression

I am trying to add a line break using dynamic expression in Azure Data Factory. Tried using a variable and setting its value as empty line and '%0A' or '%0D' but doesn't seem to work.

Sounds silly yet not able to find a way out!
Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: 'Line break' or 'New line/line feed'?  add more details (code snippet) to the question for getting help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\r,\n` or `\r\n` or `\n` to change the line using dynamic expression.

Example:

Dynamic content editor converts above content to expression `"{ \n \"type\": \"@{if(equals(1, 2), 'Blob', 'Table' )}\",\n \"name\": \"@{toUpper('myData')}\"\n}"`. The result of this expression is a JSON format string showed below.

```
{
  "type": "Table",
  "name": "MYDATA"
}
```

Learn more about Expressions and Functions in ADF [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried it but doesn't seem to work either.
So what I'm trying to do is use a web activity in data factory to post to an URL generated from logic app to send an email notification.
The web activity is built as a standalone pipeline that is parameterized with email parameters like subject, receiver, message, etc. It is this message parameter which I'm trying to break down as multiple lines from the caller pipeline. Hope that gives a better context of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

use @concat('your value','
\n
\n','Your value')

it works for me

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a similar solution as I wanted to add new line in a message that was used in Send Mail activity of Logic. I tried all approaches above but nothing worked, but this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/76655453/21954621 helped me. for. e.g

```
"message" : "@{concat('First Line','</br>','Second Line'
    ,'</br>','Third Line')}"
```